# pyspark dataframes from states to activities/changes

Tags: pyspark

Hi I have a table with a state per year. But I need the changes between these states.
So in stead of a state for each client, I want to see the changes.
These changes can be defined as a start and end date. Or transposed under each other.

Tables with states

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['A', 2018, 1],
                            ['A', 2019, 1],
                            ['A', 2020, 0],
                            ['B', 2018, 1],
                            ['B', 2019, 0],
                            ['B', 2020, 1],
                            ['C', 2018, 0],
                            ['C', 2019, 0],
                            ['C', 2020, 0],
                            ['D', 2019, 0],
                            ['D', 2020, 1],
                            ['E', 2019, 1],
                            ['E', 2020, 0],
                            ['F', 2018, 1],
                            ['F', 2019, 0],
                            ['H', 2018, 1],
                            ['H', 2019, 1],
                            ['H', 2020, 1]
                           ],
                           ['client', 'year', 'indicator']
                          )        
df.show()

+------+----+---------+
|client|year|indicator|
+------+----+---------+
|     A|2018|        1|
|     A|2019|        1|
|     A|2020|        0|
|     B|2018|        1|
|     B|2019|        0|
|     B|2020|        1|
|     C|2018|        0|
|     C|2019|        0|
|     C|2020|        0|
|     D|2019|        0|
|     D|2020|        1|
|     E|2019|        1|
|     E|2020|        0|
|     F|2018|        1|
|     F|2019|        0|
|     H|2018|        1|
|     H|2019|        1|
|     H|2020|        1|
+------+----+---------+
```

There are 2 kinds of tables I want as a result. You can choose :-)

```
Client  Begin   End
    A   2018    2020
    B   2018    2019
    B   2020    
    D   2020    
    E   2019    2020
    F   2018    2019
    H   2018
```

or

```
Client  Year    Begin or end
A   2018    Begin
A   2020    End
B   2018    Begin
B   2019    End
B   2020    Begin
H   2018    Begin
…
```

How do I do this?

I started with a transpose of the data but I'm stuck :-(

```
df_transpose = df.groupby('client').pivot('year').sum('indicator')
df_transpose.show()
+------+----+----+----+
|client|2018|2019|2020|
+------+----+----+----+
|     F|   1|   0|null|
|     E|null|   1|   0|
|     B|   1|   0|   1|
|     D|null|   0|   1|
|     C|   0|   0|   0|
|     A|   1|   1|   0|
|     H|   1|   1|   1|
+------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I can't understand your logic. For A, there is a leading 1 but you choose the next 1 to 0, however, why you choose the first 1 for H? In the sense of A, I expected the last 1 for 2020.

Comment: what if `1, 0, 0` or `1, 0, 0, 1`? So many missing parts.

Comment: I need the period when the indicator = 1.
So for A the period is only 1 year. It starts somewhere in 2019 and ends somewhere in 2020.
For H it start somewhere in 2018 and is still active in 2019 and 2020. So there is no end date.

Comment: my df.show() is wrong. A 2018 should be 0 or my in the dataframe the 2018 should be 1. Sorry

Comment: @Lamanus no more solutions? :-(